# Multivariate analysis: data transformation (ranks and others)

Tags: multivariate-analysis, data-transformation

I have a set of data with measurements of different parts of some different species. Some of these measurements are in millimeters, others are ratios.

I am using the software PAST.

Does the ranks transformation make sense in order to make data suitable for the subsequent multivariate analysis? It seems possibly the transformation allowing the best results in separating these species.

Another transformation that allows a good separation is the log transformation.

So, which is the rationale in choosing one or another?

Thanks

Comment: Let me ask you a question: why are you trying to transform the data ?

Comment: No problem for the question.
I think I need to transform data because they vary greatly among the various parts measured. For example, one part ranges between 5 and 18 mm, another between 3 and 5 mm, and the ratio are mainly below 1. So, I think that the transformation would avoid that one part would weight more than others just because it is larger and not because it is really more informative of the possible differences among the species.